# How do you make a radial diagram?

Tags: diagram, radial

Does anyone know how to create a radial diagram in .net, java, ruby, php or python?  I don't care which.  I have asked before for a library and searched everywhere.  I cannot find anything.  If I am going to build my own I thought I'd check and see if anyone knew of a resource.

The preference is to display it in a web page, if possible.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could achieve you goal with [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) / [DOT files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language).
There is a plethora of GraphViz [packages and tools](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php) for a very wide array of languages.

Comment: FYI, extreme radial diagram example made with Graphviz: http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/twopi/twopi2.html

Comment: this looks promising.  thank you.  Not sure how to set it up all up but I'll look.

Answer (score 0):

This kind? ([Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/))

[image]

Comment: no. A radial diagram is a center, nodes, child nodes and so on.  http://www.google.com/search?q=radial+diagram are the type that I mean when I say radial.  no disrespect intended by the search url.  it is just for reference.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I primary idea came to my mind is: a radial diagram (as in overdisk) can be formed of multiple cocentric pie charts:
most centric: parent nodes
least centric: leaf nodes

with an important requirement : ALIGNEMENT (every child group needs to be aligned to parents).

====
Edit: I think it can be done on web easily using Google Chart API